# Can the transition FPS drop in Injustice: Gods Among Us (PC) be fixed?

Tags: technical-issues, injustice-gods-among-us

In Injustice: Gods Among Us for PC, every time I kick someone into a wall and the [transition cutscene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LpOoMgrkgjw) plays, FPS drops significantly. Can this be fixed or is this just because of a sloppy port? I have tried the lowest possible settings and my computer more than meets recommended requirements.

Comment: Can you show something that actually shows that it's FPS drop and not TPS drop or an intentional effect of the animation sequence? I watched that video in full HD over and over and over, slowed it down even and I notice several things. First, in a few of hte shots, I do see what looks more like TPS drop. However, in most of the scenes I scrutinized, it looks intentionally designed to appear that way. Without a visual meter or something to contrast it against (like the same video without the slow played side by side synchronized by clock.) Otherwise I just see speculation.

Comment: Start with at least 5 exact time indexes in that video where you think you see FPS drop and I can then see if maybe I'm not watching the same thing you are.

Comment: Sorry, I linked the wrong video! I've edited my post for the correct one. Take a look at the 1:20 or 1:35 mark. The lag on my game is actually even worse than the video most of the time but this is the best video displaying the issue that I could find.

Comment: much better, and yeah, now I see what you are talking about

Comment: I guess you're talking about that little lag right before the fight continues like normal? Thats not FPS drop.. The second the games lags is the point where the game loads the new part of the arena and it seems like it's not fast enough to load smooth. Are you playing on the same hard drive as your OS is running? HDD or SSD?

Comment: I have actually monitored the FPS. It drops from 60 to 15-30. The game doesn't drop below 60 FPS during normal gameplay. As I said, it's much worse on my end than in this video during these stage transitions. The game is on the same HDD as my OS. Steam users with SSDs have reported the same issue. It's also non-existent on consoles and my hardware is more than sufficient.

Comment: @ydobonebi: What is "TPS"?  The only thing I can find online is "ticks per second" but that obviously doesn't apply here.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I didn't know either and had to Google it myself. I found the same information. It doesn't seem like it would apply to offline play.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft TPS is Ticks Per Second, but really just one term for it. He changed the video so I don't really have a basis to compare, but sometimes what people see as FPS lag, really is TPS lag. In fact more often than not unless you're loading a new area of a game, then it will be TPS instead. And how would it not apply to offline play? TPS has nothing to do with mulltiplayer or online play.

Comment: @ydobonebi Sorry, I'm pretty ignorant on this matter. I assumed TPS had to do with tick rate because the only time I've ever heard it mentioned is playing Counter-Strike and Google yields only results about Minecraft. If it is TPS lag how can I fix it? (If it can be fixed.) Or if it's not, what is the best way to tell what is causing this issue?

Comment: @Spectro Are you talking about the little lag that happens just before the game resumes, or do you have low fps through the whole transition cutscene?

Comment: @svj0hn Throughout the entire cutscene.